# Hola Mi programa kivy funciona pero al momento de pasar a apk no funciona

Tags: python, apk, kivy

cuando paso a apk mi programa kivy no funciona pero anda cuando esta en archivo .py en mi programa uso las librerias kivy, openai y nada mas que ya las puse en el archivo buildozer.spec esta es la linea donde las puse:

```
requirements = python3,kivy,openai
```

Comment: Hola Julito, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código y los mensajes de error (si es que los recibes) en formato texto, y que nos expliques en que falla, mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada. aprovecha y haz el recorrido de Bienvenida para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!